# .net core 8.0.0 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core (3.21.130) can't "Open()"

Tags: .net, oracle, .net-core

We wrote a very simple console POC, we remove almost every line and the Main looks like this

```
static void Main()
{
    string _connectionstring = "Data Source=<name from TNS file>;User Id=<my user id>;Proxy User Id=<a service account>;Proxy Password=<the service account password>";
    using (OracleConnection _cn = new OracleConnection(_connectionstring))
    {
      _cn.Open();
    }
}
```

the `_cn.Open()` always fails with 'Connection request timed out'

the exception is happening at:

```
OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager<PM,CP, CR>
......
```

things we tried:

- adjusting the min and max pool size, give us same error
- try to increase the time out, but that raises an error that can't parse the connection string even though we are using the right parameter syntax.

regards,

changed the connection string by adding removing additional parameters

Comment: Can you connect with another tool? What is your database version?

Comment: Does the connection string work with another client application? If not, then fix your connection string. If it does, then check that the driver you are using is compatible with the database version and that the database is accessible from the client (i.e. not blocked by a firewall), etc.

Comment: Thanks both for your quick response. From my workstation I can connect using any of the Oracle clients: sqplus, sqldeveloper, others.  From my machine I can connect using legacy .net.  The only issue is with .net core (we are using version 8.0.0).  On net core we are using Oracle.ManageDataAccess.Core since any other driver does not work with .net core.  we are using Oracle 12